# Axios created string returns 403 forbidden since the URL is broken but works fine hardcoded string

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

Axios created string returns 403 forbidden since the URL is broken when the URL is made by combining several strings.

Here is an example:
This works fine:

```
const inventory = await axios.get("http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198164672016/730/2?l=english&count=5000");
```

It returns the correct results.

But when using the same URL, just combining different values, it does not work.

```
const testId = 76561198164672016;
const path = "http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/"+testId.toString()+"/730/2?l=english&count=5000"
    const inventoryWithPath = await axios.get(path);
```

This returns an error. I don't understand how this can happen when the strings are the same...
Here is the full code.

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const testId = 76561198164672016;


async function getInventory(){
    try{

    //invetory works fine and returns correct values
    const inventory = await axios.get("http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/76561198164672016/730/2?l=english&count=5000");

    //Even though this has the same URL it returns an error. Why and how can I request based on the path?
    const path = "http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/"+testId.toString()+"/730/2?l=english&count=5000"
    const inventoryWithPath = await axios.get(path);
    
    //console.log(inventoryWithPath)
    console.log(inventory)
    return inventory;
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Error happened")
    }
}
module.exports={getInventory}
```

Comment: @Mina it's included in the code

Comment: Weird `76561198164672016..toString()` results in `'76561198164672020'`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have also tried `const testId = 76561198164672016; let textId = testId.toString();` but that also didnt work

Comment: 76561198164672016 is > than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - try `76561198164672016n`

Comment: The easier fix would be to not use number at all. Just use the string.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski - assuming the number isn't needed for some other purpose :p - but you're 100% right

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, the reason your code isn't working is because `testId > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. What you can do to solve this is use **BigInt** like this:

`const path = "http://steamcommunity.com/inventory/" + BigInt(testId).toString() + "/730/2?l=english&count=5000"`